# Can someone explain me Python Division

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Why is 100./3. = 33.33333333333333**6** and **NOT** 33.33333333333333**3** OR 33.33333333333333**4** ?

```
>>> a = 100./3.
>>> a
33.333333333333336
>>> b = a + a + a
>>> b
100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

the wrong digit at the end is because of imprecision in representing the decimal as binary data in the interpreter; the interpreter is usually good at correcting those wrong-digits